# Issue creating button in which opens a window/stage

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller

Im having issues with understanding what should be the model in my ViewLoader statement while making a JavaFXML MVC project

I have a button on the main menu in which when the user clicks it will take me to another window called known as the build menu.
Ive tried a multitude of possible models that I think would work including getBuild etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rQsP.jpg

Here is a screenshot of my Controller and View file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWev1.jpg

Here is a screenshot of my Model file

The expected result based off a similar project ive found online is that when the button is clicked a new window pops up. Im assuming the reason this doesnt work is because the getBuild method/statement needs to be initialised in the Controller class however I am unsure as of how to do that as getBuild is a method in my Model class

Answer (score 0):

If you are only Navigating from one scene (window) to another the code is as listed below. Why do you think you need to have a MVC pattern to do this is is confusing.
Here is the code to go from one scene to another we name all our Anchor Pane's somenamePane so we know where we are and where we are going.

```
    public void goTO() throws IOException, SQLException{
    stage = (Stage)paneStart.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    ckbookPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("manager.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(ckbookPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("checkbook.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Check Book Manager"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen(); 
}
```